# Would it be possible to share a libvirt guests network connection with the host?

Tags: linux, networking, libvirt

If you were to (for example) passthrough the hosts ethernet and wifi to a guest, would it be possible to share the guests network connection with the host in some way?

Answer (score 0):

No, you either need two distinct public IP addresses for the VM and the host (like if bridging host ethernet), or you have one public IP address but use NAT on the host to differentiate host and VM with non-public IP addresses (default libvirt and docker work this way).

Think of it like if your house and your neighbors house down the street had the exact same address. How would the post office know who to deliver a letter to? Either the houses need different addresses (case #1), or the post office needs to do some extra filtering based on who it is addressed to (kinda like NAT case #2).